# Flutter: MediaQuery.of(context).size is not match emulator screen size

Tags: android, flutter, media-queries, screen-size

I am using flutter 3.3.2 on Android SDK v31.0.0

I created an emulator with screen size 6.1 inch - 393 x 852, but the screen size return from MediaQuery is different as below:

- MediaQuery.of(context).size.width= 394
- MediaQuery.of(context).size.height = 804
- MediaQuery.of(context).size.devicePixelRatio = 1

Could anyone help me to explain why it is different ? Or did i miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

use MediaQuery like this method it will take auto screen size.

write inside BuildContext.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //write here

    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width  = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return new Container(
      height :height,
      width : width,
      color :Colors.red,
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course i have to called MediaQuery.of(context)  inside the BuildContext method to get the "context" parameter. However, thanks to your advise, i found my answers. I fill the container with green, and figure out that the container does not cover the bottom navigation bar. Thanks a lot guy !

Comment: good to hear it

Answer (score 0):

Finally i figured out the reason. The difference is because out the system navigation bar at the bottom screen. I disable it by setting the hw.mainKeys=yes. Then the size is returned by MediaQuery is equal to emulator screen size.